Gitlab pipeline status never finish
I am creating a gitlab pipeline when files from specific folders are changing.
My rule is
.sca_deploy_rules:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      changes:
        paths:
          - "force-app/main/default/**/*"
      when: always
    - when: never

When i creating a MR with any file that is not in the paths. The pipeline is not finishing
Pipeline status
I'd like to prevent run pipelines when i am commiting any file that are not inside of the directory   force-app/main/default/**/*

Also had this problem once. In my case it just worked when i refreshed the MR page in the browser. Did you try that? Also, are you running on gitlab.com or self-hosted?
